# Chamisha Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psalms 145 (Ashrei, Tehila L'Dovid) is said three times daily.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, *Terach* was 145 years old when *Avraham* went on his "*lech-l'cha*" trip, but I have no good source for this.

Comment: Rashi to Gen. 11:32.

Comment: Thank you, R'Alex! And for the lazy among us (like me), here's a link: http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8175/showrashi/true#v1132

Answer (score 0):

Yitzchok was 145 years old when Reuvain was born.

Yaakov got married at 84

Yitzchok was 144

Reuvain was born a year later to Leah when Yitchok was 145 - Or Yitzchak was 145 when Simon was born. Reuven birth: 14 Kislev  Shimon birth: 28 Teveis

Comment: That probably depends on whether Reuvain's birth was before or after Peasch.